# Why can't the schema see the required array?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have created a JSON Schema, but when I try to use it to validate another object, the schema fails due to an error, citing:

Message:
Required properties are missing from object: Envelope.
Schema path:
#/required

However, I can clearly see the required array listed inside of the envelope as a sibling to its properties. In every schema I've seen online, this is how is is displayed. I have included a trimmed-down selection of the schema below that still sees the same error. Can anyone tell me why this is failing?

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Envelope": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "TP_UNIQUE_NUM": {
                    "length": 50,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "SENDER_ID": {
                    "length": 50,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "TRANSMISSION_FORMAT": {
                    "length": 50,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "RECEIVER_ID": {
                    "length": 50,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "HEADER": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "door": {
                            "description": "Door at which product associated with ASN is scheduled to be unloaded",
                            "type": "string",
                            "mandatory": "Y",
                            "maxLength": 10
                        },
                        "notes": {
                            "description": "Comments associated with ASN",
                            "type": "string",
                            "mandatory": "Y",
                            "maxLength": 4000
                        },
                        "wareHouseReference": {
                            "description": "Additional notes or reference information for the warehouse",
                            "type": "string",
                            "mandatory": "Y",
                            "maxLength": 100
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "wareHouseReference"
                    ]
                },
                "TP_TRANSMISSION_TYPE": {
                    "maxLength": 50,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "FILE_NAME": {
                    "maxLength": 50,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "TRANSMISSION_DATE_TIME": {
                    "maxLength": 50,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "TRANSACTION_COUNT": {
                    "maxLength": 50,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "Envelope"
    ]
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your schema. The error sounds like it's telling you that the data you are validating doesn't have the required property "Envelope".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing a `required` array within the `Envelope` object.

You have a `required` array at the root level object, you also have one within the `HEADER` object, but not within the `Envelope` object.

I'm assuming a `required` array is required for each object type.

EDIT: My assumption is probably wrong, I was able to run your schema at [json-schema-validator](https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/) without an issue using this sample JSON. @Jason Desrosiers comment seems to be right on the money.

```
{
  "Envelope": {
    "TP_UNIQUE_NUM": "hello",
    "SENDER_ID": "hello",
    "TRANSMISSION_FORMAT": "hello",
    "RECEIVER_ID": "hello",
    "HEADER": {
       "door": "hello",
       "notes": "hello",
       "wareHouseReference": "hello"
     },
    "TP_TRANSMISSION_TYPE": "hello",
    "FILE_NAME": "hello",
    "TRANSMISSION_DATE_TIME": "hello",
    "TRANSACTION_COUNT": "hello"
  }
}
```